# .htaccess not redirecting HTTPS to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website with SSL. The redirect from http to https seems to work fine. my problem is how should I redirect the https://example.com to https://www.example.com.
I have tries this but it's not working.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule .? https://%1%2 [R=301,L,U,NE]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```